# Centering by aboslute position works vertically, but not horizontaly

Tags: html, css, centering

Can somebody explain me, why the `.centered` div in `horizontal` `wrapper` gets centered but the one in `vertical` does not? Even when same principles are applied?

They both have absolute positioning, both have zeroes from edges, relative to which, they should be centered, and both have margin: auto. Yet one is centered and another is not.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

#vertical { 
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}

#horizontal {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
}

#horizontal .centered {
  height: 60px;
  width: 20px;  
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}


#vertical .centered {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;  
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal" class="wrapper">
  <div class="centered">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="vertical" class="wrapper">
  <div class="centered">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into flexbox?  Absolute positioning is something I rarely use; it is for very niche applications.  Generally you just want flexbox if you are centering stuff.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You'd probably have to dig into the CSS specification quite a bit. Somewhere in there the relation between width, height and the position "edges" should be detailed, and which are the "weaker" ones when it comes to resolving conflicts.

Comment: Did you take the time to read the duplicate and follow the links? The duplicate is giving your the full detail taken from the specification in relation to how position:absolute should be place in both axis. Simply read it *fully* and apply it to your case.

Comment: To give you a hint, you will clearly see from the specification that vertical and horizontal don't have the same rules and for the horizontal version the "direction" property is considered. And this point is clearly mentioned in the duplicate answer at the end. Just read it *fully*

Comment: @TemaniAfif response to the duplicate only states, that vertical is "almost same":
Almost the same is considered when it comes to the vertical direction (top, bottom and height): https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height
So I don't see how that helps me and how that is duplicate to my question.